# rdd transform to get k-gram tuples in pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Take the sentence: "This is apache spark". I want to be able to transform each word into list of tuples if they are k distance away. Example: k=2, I should get [(apache,this), (apache, is)] for the word apache. Similarly for is, spark etc.

I first use zipWithIndex on rdd and then in the transform function call a loop from 1 to k behind the current word. But I don't know how to get the word at some index say i-2 where i is index of my current word.

```
rdd.zipWithIndex().flatMap(lambda xi: func(xi,n))
def func(xi, n):
    x,i = xi
    l=[]
    for j in range(n):
        #Create tuple (word at i-j, x) but how
```